# Adding a button to a RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, awt, rcp

I want to add a button to a RCP client. The window needs to display my barChart as well as 3 buttons.

When i add the line:
                    panel.add(button);
it returns an error:
                    The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Button)

Please help :)

```
@Override
    protected void createWindows(final Shell shell) throws Exception {
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.EMBEDDED);

        final Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite); 
        final StaticBarSketch barGraph = new StaticBarSketch();
        final Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Press");

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.add(barGraph);
        frame.add(panel);
        barGraph.init();

        composite.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                barGraph.resized(composite.getSize().x, composite.getSize().y);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is it `java.awt.Button` ? If it is then `button.setText("Press");` shoudl throw compilation error.

Comment: import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button; :) removing the setText does nothing to the errror i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `Panel`, use `Composite`. `Panel` is from `Swing` and you are mixing `Swing` with RCP/SWT, which is not wise.

The `Button` that you are using is from SWT and you are adding that to `Panel` which is a `Swing` component and you can only a `Swing` component to `Panel`. You can either change the `Button` to `AWT`'s `Button` or `Swing`s `JButton`. Otherwise as stated earlier, change the `Panel` to `Composite`.